# How to skip a line with a syntax error in Java/Processing?

Tags: java, error-handling, syntax-error, processing

I have a program that generates a bunch of code snippets, most of which are syntactically usable, but some of which are not.  The ones that don't might look like

```java
return 2.0+0.0+pow(2.0),2.0;
```

I have been unable to modify my original code to avoid these issues, but I suppose this could be fixed by some method to test if a string contains syntactically correct code.

Here's an example of my code.  This entire file would be saved from another program to be run afterwards.

```java
{
print(myFun());
}

float myFun() {
  return 2.0+0.0+pow(2.0),2.0;
  return 10;
}
```

The first line of the function obviously has syntax issues (i.e, not enough arguments in pow() and an out-of-place comma), so the code will not compile.  My hope would be that there is something, possibly similar to a `try` ... `catch` block, to simply skip over this unusable line and move on to the next.

Thanks in advance!

Just for reference, I'm using Processing 4.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah to my knowledge, try-catch block is your best bet here. There might be someone else though that might know a different way

Comment: I tried a `try` ... `catch` block, but it didn't work, because they don't catch syntax- and other compilation-errors.  I need something to trick the compiler.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @RowanAckerman if it's a compile-time error, you'd probably have to manually fix the syntax yourself, but if it is a run-time error, a try-catch should work

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to test a string like I mentioned?

Comment: Could you tell me what the exception is exactly that it returns?

Comment: I don't think it's giving me an exception, rather it's a syntax error.  Here it is anyway: `Syntax Error - Missing operator, semicolon, or '}' near ','?`

Comment: Install a java file, convert to executable, execute with try, error, goto except

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Run you program, check output using javac, look at the exit code. If non zero, rerun your code generation code with more strict output if that is possible.